# How do I convert the following to preg_replace_callback (for use in PHP 7.3.2)

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

Trying to get the code below to not use the `/e` modifier (using `preg_replace_callback`) instead.

```
private function encodeHeader($input, $charset = 'ISO-8859-1')
{
    preg_match_all('/(\w*[\x80-\xFF]+\w*)/', $input, $matches);
    foreach ($matches[1] as $value) {
        $replacement = preg_replace('/([\x80-\xFF])/e', '"=" . strtoupper(dechex(ord("\1")))', $value);
        $input = str_replace($value, '=?' . $charset . '?Q?' . $replacement . '?=', $input);
    }

    return $input;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use an anonymous function to return what you had, using the `$m` parameter as the matches, so `$m[1]` instead of `\1`:

```
$replacement = preg_replace_callback('/([\x80-\xFF])/',
                                     function($m) {
                                         return "=" . strtoupper(dechex(ord($m[1])));
                                     }, $value);
```

If you just use `'/[\x80-\xFF]/'` with no capture group, then you use `$m[0]`.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH for your answer, that was very helpful  :)